# How to use superagent-mock as temporary backend

Tags: javascript, superagent

So taken from the superagent website, it says that "With this tip, you can develop the frontend without access to any API. It’s very useful in order to work locally on your computer, without the internet, or to make your functional tests independent of any third party."

I created a config file :

```
// ./config.js file
module.exports = [
  {
    pattern: 'http://tech.m6web.fr/api/authors',
    fixtures: './authors.js',
    callback: function (match, data) {
      return { body : data };
    }
];
```

Mocked up data to be returned by the rest call:

```
// ./authors.js file
module.exports = function () {
  return [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John Doe",
      description: "unidentified person"
    },
    ...
  ];
};
```

What is next? It says to put

```
// ./server.js file
var request = require('superagent');
var config = require('./config.js');
var mock = require('superagent-mock')(request, config);
```

In the server.js file. Is this the file where I currently have my rest services defined? Replace the `request` imported from superagent with the `mock` variable created?

Instead of `request.get(url)...`:

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=> {request.get(url).end((err,res)=> { err?reject(err):resolve(res) }); }).then(...)
```

Use the mock variable created? `mock.get(url)...`

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=> {mock.get(url).end((err,res)=> { err?reject(err):resolve(res) }); }).then(...)
```

But `var mock` is null.. is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is the simpliest example of superagent-mock configuration:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var mock = require('superagent-mock');

var config = [
    {
        pattern: 'https://domain.example(.*)',
        fixtures: function (match, params, headers) {
            return 'foo'
        },
        get: function (match, data) {
            return data
        }
    }
];

mock(request, config);

request
    .get('https://domain.example')
    .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res); // ===> foo
    });
```

It looks like api changed from times of this post http://tech.m6web.fr/how-did-we-mock-the-backend-developers.html. Official api on github is fine https://github.com/M6Web/superagent-mock.